# Do i have to pay tax if my friends father transfer money monthly to my account to give him

Tags: income-tax, india

My friend doesn't have a bank account so his father transfers money to my account monthly, rs 20,000/- for that do I have to pay any tax?

Comment: Is there any good reason you friend can't open his own account? (You shouldn't have to pay any tax if you do this, but there seems to be no legitimate reason to do it this way.)

Comment: Once or twice? Not a big deal. Every month? As keshlam said, he should get an account of his own.

Comment: Isn't the Indian annual gift tax exemption amount INR 50K or so for unrelated parties? So, unless your friend's father is a _relative_ of yours (that you call him "Chachaji" out of politeness does not make him a _relative_ of yours), there would be gift tax due on the transfer from friend's father to you, and also on the transfer from you to your friend. So, follow @keshlam's advice and get your friend to open his own account, so that his father can transfer money to him directly without any gift tax issues.  Note for nonIndian readers: "Chachaji" means "Honoured Uncle".

Answer (score 1):

> do I have to pay any tax?

Technically this would be treated as Gift from non relatives and taxes as per gift tax rules. There is a limit of Rs 50,000 per year to receive funds from non-relatives. Note if the amount becomes Rs 50,001 then the entire Rs 50,001 is taxable.

If you are again giving this money to your friend, then your friend is also liable to pay Gift Tax on the money received.

It is best recommended that you have your friend open an account.